# Optimistic work sharing on sparsely distributed systems

Tags: concurrency, distributed-computing

What would a system like [BOINC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Open_Infrastructure_for_Network_Computing) look like if it were written today? 
At the time BOINC was written, databases were the primary choice for maintaining a shared state and concurrency among nodes.

Since then, many approaches have been developed for tasking with optimistic concurrency (OT, synchronization primitives like vector clocks, virtual synchrony, shared iterators etc.)

Is there a paradigm for optimistically distributing units of work on sparsely distributing systems which communicate through message passing?

Sorry if this is a bit vague.

P.S.
The concept of [Tuple-spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space) is great, but locking is inherent to its definition.

**Edit2**:

The entire system is sparsely distributed - they can communicate only through WAN. And communication *can* be slow and faulty. The question is about how to best distribute units of work among them without a central co-ordinator and with as little consensus as possible (because consensus is expensive).

The answers here seem to be talking about databases - data isn't the problem. The problem is in distributing work.

**Edit**:

I already have a federation system which works well. I'm looking to extend it to get clients to do units of work.

Answer (score 2):

When you know what your system really needs is when you can choose the better solution. The biggest data systems are made for great amounts of data, if your system has little data (GBs) then one typical solution will fit. You must think that big sparse data systems require special data models that are very different from SQL typical data models.

RDBMS data models look forward to represent a consistent state in every moment, distributed systems don't (see [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Data is not the problem here - the system has eventual consistency, and leans more toward availability. The problem is how to use whatever data model exists and use that to assign work to distributed units.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is usually the best. There's nothing wrong with a central server distributing work to a number of workers provided you can make the jobs big enough that the overhead is not overwhelming. There's no point redesigning BOINC just because fashions have changed.

Comment: The easiest solution is easy precisely because it puts a set of constraints on the working of the system, reducing the system complexity. E.g., Having event handling code running on the GUI event-loop is the easiest solution. When the code is computationally intensive, you cause the GUI to become unresponsive. You will have traded the easy solution for the constraint that you will have an unresponsive GUI.

Comment: I appreciate the honest answer, but it is akin asking for a solution like Operational Transformations for collaborative editing and being told that you should stick to database transactions because it is easy.

Comment: @Asti, except that database transactions aren't a valid answer when you are looking for Operational Transformations; it doesn't solve the problem. What do you lose in this case from having a centralized architecture? Not enough to warrant the increased complexity.

Comment: All the conventional problems of a Master-Slave architecture, Dan. Single point of failure, bottle-necks due due to load on master, messages required to acquire a lock, reentrancy, task deadlines...
I'm looking for a shift which could mitigate classic problems early on.

Comment: But you inherit all of the problems of a master-master architecture, complicated error cases etc. There's no need for locking, optimistic concurrency is possible.

Comment: In a Master-Client setup, how does one ensure actions are not duplicated without locking?

Comment: @Asti, the GHC runtime has to manage the computation of thunks, (which are pure functions that take no arguments). What it does is to allow any thread to compute any thunk and it periodically does a scan to ensure that the same thunk isn't being computed in more than one thread. So many threads don't waste time computing the same large thunks. The point is, there are many ways to handle this situation without explicit locking. Choosing the right solution is going to depend mainly on the size distribution of the tasks. If the tasks are consistently large, then a lock with a timeout is fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2223/discussion-between-asti-and-dan-waterworth)

Comment: The above solution is okay when:
1. Computation creates no side-effects
2. You have immediate access to the state of computation

This isn't the case with a sparsely distributed system. But I see your point. I'll look into systems which deal with the concurrency side of it first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if programming is like clothing industry so if you won't redesign the system each 2 weeks your friends will laugh at you because you lost sync with fashion? :)

If it was written today probably marketing team would stick a big "cloud" banner to it, it'd require 20 amazon nodes to run at decent speed and would break at least 5 times daily because of using latest-and-greatest "nosql storage". Then you'd face scalability problems because those cloud systems usually don't scale out of the box as they promise, and you'd be forced to re-think the design.

Today it's for sure a little different. You could for example manage the state using some mature nosql solution like memcached for staging and then just put the data into SQL. What's wrong with the old approach if you can get a server with 64GB Ram and 24 cores for something like $300-$500.

Comment: My friend, I'm looking for a paradigm like Tuple spaces, not a set of programs that I need chain or a database to run on Amazon or Azure.